# Command to insert a line of code immediately below the first php open tag and in multiple files

Tags: php, ssh, sed, command

I am patching a xss vulnerability. I need to insert my patch which is

```
if (isset($_GET['Mobile'])){ $_GET['Mobile']=htmlentities($_GET['Mobile']); }
```

immediately after the opening php tag in about 70 php files. The tricky part is that each file contains multiple php opening tags and I only want this code to be to injected below the first php opening tag and not the rest.

I attempted to use the line oriented commands `a\` and `i\`. I am unsure if these can be used at the same time or if I formatted it wrong.

`sed -i -e '/<?php/a\/ini_set('display_errors', 'off');/i\if (isset($_GET['Mobile'])){ $_GET['Mobile']=htmlentities($_GET['Mobile']); }' *amenities.php`

When I run the code above it inserts the code below into all php opening tags instead of just the first one.

`if (isset($_GET['Mobile'])){ $_GET['Mobile']=htmlentities($_GET['Mobile']); }`

I am also assuming the first couple line of code of each php file that I am adjusting is the same which is

`<?php`

`ini_set('display_errors', 'off');`

If there is a better way to approach this please let me know I am open to ideas. First time poster anything is appreciated.

Comment: Yes I realize I stated xss scripting vulnerability which is redundant. I am looking for an edit button.

Comment: Welcoem to SO! [Here's the edit button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65638165/edit). Have you made an attempt at solving this?

Comment: I have yes. I attempted to use the line oriented commands a\ and i\ on the command. It did not work since it inserted code into every opening php tag and not between the opening php tag and the second line of code ini_set('display_errors', 'off'); which I am assuming every file i am editing has the same first 3 lines of code. I am unsure if my mistake is that I formatted it wrong or if it is not possible. This is the command I tried sed -i -e '/<?php/a\/ini_set('display_errors', 'off');/i\if (isset($_GET['Mobile'])){ $_GET['Mobile']=htmlentities($_GET['Mobile']); }' *amenities.php

Comment: Thanks, but please make that an edit to the post. I can't make heads or tails of it here.

Comment: you want to use this structure: `/?>php/{' ... '}`... in that structure, I suggest `r the-file-containing-text-you-want-to-insert;q`.  `r` will read in the contents of the file, `q` will say that you're done editing the stream so that it all only happens on the 1st matching line.